# DataTable mysterious ConstraintException concerning PrimaryKey

Tags: c#, .net

I am using a DataTable to fill a grid view with data from a translation dictionary - literally a `Dictionary<string, string>` using the following code:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("key", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("value", typeof(string));
dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns[0] };
foreach(var key in localizer.Keys)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row[0] = key;
    row[1] = localizer[key];
    dt.Rows.Add(row); // this line throws an error even though identifiers are ascii
                      // and contain no spaces
}
```

I tried creating the primary key constraint after the loop, but then it throws another exception stating that the column contains values that are not unique. The value where it stops is `"evalDate"` and there are two other similar keys `"evalDateStart"` and `"evalDateEnd"` but none are identical - which is logical since they are read from a dictionary.

Comment: What exactly is the exeception thrown?

Comment: `System.Data.ConstraintException`: "Column 'key' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'evalDate' is already present."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually by looking into it a bit I found the missing piece of the puzzle. The dictionary compares strings by value in a case sensitive manner, but the DataTable object compares strings by value in a case insensitive manner.
The trigger was a misused resource key that was all lowercase which resulted in the keys 'evaldate' and 'evalDate' both being present in the dictionary. It also explains why the exception was erratic, it only happened if we accessed a certain page during tests.

Comment: I don't think a `Dictionary<K,V>` compares keys by reference, but you're probably correct about the issue being about case sensitivity.

Comment: A `DataTable` uses case-insensitive comparisons by default: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.casesensitive.aspx